# How we will get different field label for different record type?

Tags: administration, record-type, label

I have certain requirement in which i have to relabel the standard amount field on the opportunity Object for particular record type.For example if there are 6 record types named A,B,C,D,E,F then i have to relabel amount field for only A,B,C record type.I know about we can do it by going into setup->rename tabs and label, but this will do it for entire org.

Comment: Are you going to use this all label in visualforce page or in standard page layout ?

Comment: @Nihar I need this functionality in standard page layout and i need to this without the help of code

Comment: Okay, let me post alternate solution for your scenario !!

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander posted Standard functionality doesn't allow to do this and use visualforce page and override it to the standard one. If you don't need to do with the help of code then i have alternate solution for this scenario as following,

**Step 1 :** Create formula fields in your respective object

(for example : Lable - Amount A, Data type : Number/Currency, formula : Object.Amount)

**Step 2 :** I believe you have created few page layouts and assigned that page layouts to the different record type. So, just hide the standard `Amount` field from the page layout and add the created formula field to the page layout

(for example : Record type - A, Page layout - A, formula field - Amount A)

Do follow the same steps for each record type and post comment if you have any question regarding this solution.

Hope it helps you out !!

Comment: Creating a new field with new name can be one solution but making it formula field is not appropriate becoz formula fields are read only fields and amount field on opportunity  are editable field until an opportunity line item not added ,as soon as oli added it become read only field.I need same kind of functionality.

Comment: Okay, if you need that kind of solution then create a field using data type with TEXT/Currency/Number and populate it with the help of workflow rule/ Process builder/ApexTrigger. it will surely help you to make that field editable as amount.

Answer (score 0):

Standard functionality doesn't allow to do this. it can be implemented in the following way.

1. Store proper pair recordtype=label values in [Custom Metadata types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ua%2F&type=0)
2. Create VF page, that displays correct label.
3. Override standard view with new VF page

if lightning experience is used, do the same, but by means of lightning components and lightning pages